# SQL Server 2016 AlwaysOn VDI_CLIENT_WORKER command

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups

I've setup an AlwaysOn AG on SQL Server 2016 SP1 Standard. Then I created an AG and added a database with autoseeding (synchronous mode). I used SSMS 2017 to create my AG and to add the database. Everything works fine.

But when I check the wait stats I get waits of type VDI_CLIENT_OTHER (80%) on the primary with an average resource time of 42 seconds. After some research I found out that the waits are generated by 4 sessions that execute the command VDI_CLIENT_WORKER. As I understand the wait means that a thread is waiting for work when seeding a new AG. But what I do not understand is why I have those waits because my AG is ready and why do I have 4 sessions that execute the VDI_CLIENT_WORKER command?
I found out that each scheduler has one VDI_CLIENT_WORKER

Can somebody try to explain what VDI_CLIENT_WORKER-command does and how can I solve the problem of the many VDI_CLIENT_OTHER waits?

Comment: What query did you use to get your wait stats?

Comment: @StijnWynants I've used a query of Paul Randal (https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/capturing-wait-statistics-period-time/)

Comment: That are accumulated statistics, is the server in production yet?

Comment: @StijnWynants this query takes a two snapshots (at start and in my case one after 2 minutes). And then shows the waits that occurred

Comment: Why do you think this is a problem? Seems like the database seeded perfectly fine, in a quick amount of time, without any issues.

Comment: @SeanGallardy-Microsoft I've another SQL Server 2016 SP1 AG where I do not see those waits. I was wondering why one server shows those waits and another doesn't. They are both seeded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some more research I discovered that when I create an AG with autoseeding SQL Server creates a new worker (that executes the VDI_CLIENT_WORKER command) for each scheduler. 
To remove those workers I need remove every 'autoseeded' AG and restart the SQL Server service.

If I then create the AG with full backup/restore none of these workers are created.

Comment: I had exactly the same behavior. No way to kill the processes, they are marked as system. The sessions seem to do nothing.

Comment: I didn't have to restart the SQL Server service, but I did have to remove the DB from the AG and then re-add it using "Skip initial data synchronization".